# twitch view count resets to take away bots

Tags: objective-c, proxy, httpresponse, asihttprequest, twitch

Hello before everyone gets all worked up over a viewbot I want to say its just a project for fun and I just wanted to try it to see if it would actually work and learn stuff along the way.  I have no interest in releasing this or trying to become parter or seriously bot people maybe just play a prank on my friend who wants to stream now and again. Now that that is said I can get on with it.

I wrote a basic program that builds twitch viewer tokens and then and then starts connecting them to where I believe twitch counts it view.  Here is the strange thing when I hit 10 bots it resets the viewer count to the accrual real viewers.  My question is how the heck does it figure it out.  I would like to note I am using proxies to connect so that twitch thinks these viewers are from around the world and not coming from one single location.
There is another way that i have tried and it is to build up all the viewer tokens and then instead like above where i get a view token and send it immediately I build them all up based on the proxies then send them all at the same time and this normally does goes above the 10 viewer cap but not by much however it does not reset back to the accrual viewer count.

Here is the code that builds the tokens: (a little messy so I will answer any questions that need to be answered about it)

```
 ASIHTTPRequest *request43 = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/%@/access_token?as3=t",_twitchName]]];
        [request43 setProxyHost:host];
        [request43 setProxyPort:port];
[request43 addRequestHeader:@"Host" value:@"api.twitch.tv"];
[request43 addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"];
[request43 addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"];
[request43 addRequestHeader:@"Accept-Language" value:@"en-US,en;q=0.5"];
[request43 addRequestHeader:@"Accept-Encoding" value:@"gzip, deflate"];
[request43 addRequestHeader:@"Referer" value:@"http://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.rc356cd0c16b6941b7f81b61f6c81628e0af555d9.swf"];
[request43 addRequestHeader:@"Cookie" value:@" __qca=P0-1674306474-1405279259134; __utma=165406266.651051162.1405279260.1417284372.1417380722.33; __utmz=165406266.1411832471.26.8.utmcsr=twitch.tv|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/nozux; language=en-us; __gads=ID=bc1b6635a26dc0a7:T=1405279267:S=ALNI_MY1rrxM6Qf6aS_lUCRlff0o0gtUaA; unique_id=e8ba8f001f90b6bc293ab6e79ea0b1bb; __utmc=165406266; feature_bucket=88; _twitch_session_id=c06f09efe4c36c8ea46176deabab0cb5; __utmb=165406266.0.10.1417380722; mp_809576468572134f909dffa6bd0dcfcf_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22147312bcdb989-0fc383a2c86945-41652d42-13c680-147312bcdba176%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fintl.gg%2F%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22intl.gg%22%7D"];
[request43 addRequestHeader:@"Connection" value:@"keep-alive"];
[request43 addRequestHeader:@"If-None-Match" value:@"11b92749f327a27cb4ebfb8b57f12b15"];
[request43 addRequestHeader:@"Cache control" value:@"no-cache"];
        [request43 setTimeOutSeconds:10];
        [request43 setFailedBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"failed 1st");
            NSLog(@"%@",request43.error);
        }];
        [request43 setCompletionBlock:^{

            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:request43.responseData options:0 error:&error];
            NSString *token = [[jsonDic valueForKey:@"token"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                               NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            NSString *sig = [jsonDic valueForKey:@"sig"];
            NSLog(@"%@",jsonDic);

            ASIHTTPRequest *request44 = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://usher.twitch.tv/api/channel/hls/%@.m3u8?token=%@&p=4753325&player=twitchweb&sig=%@&segment_preference=4",_twitchName,token,sig]]];
            ////http//usher.twitch.tv/api/channel/hls/%@.m3u8?token=%@&p=4753325&player=twitchweb&sig=%@&segment_preference=4
                           [request44 addRequestHeader:@"Host" value:@"usher.twitch.tv"];
            [request44 addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"];
            [request44 addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"];
            [request44 addRequestHeader:@"Accept-Language" value:@"en-US,en;q=0.5"];
            [request44 addRequestHeader:@"Accept-Encoding" value:@"gzip, deflate"];
            [request44 addRequestHeader:@"Referer" value:@"http://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.rc356cd0c16b6941b7f81b61f6c81628e0af555d9.swf"];
            [request44 addRequestHeader:@"Cookie" value:@" __qca=P0-1674306474-1405279259134; __utma=165406266.651051162.1405279260.1417284372.1417380722.33; __utmz=165406266.1411832471.26.8.utmcsr=twitch.tv|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/nozux; language=en-us; __gads=ID=bc1b6635a26dc0a7:T=1405279267:S=ALNI_MY1rrxM6Qf6aS_lUCRlff0o0gtUaA; unique_id=e8ba8f001f90b6bc293ab6e79ea0b1bb; __utmc=165406266; feature_bucket=88; _twitch_session_id=c06f09efe4c36c8ea46176deabab0cb5; __utmb=165406266.0.10.1417380722; mp_809576468572134f909dffa6bd0dcfcf_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22147312bcdb989-0fc383a2c86945-41652d42-13c680-147312bcdba176%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fintl.gg%2F%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22intl.gg%22%7D"];
            [request44 addRequestHeader:@"Connection" value:@"keep-alive"];
            [request44 addRequestHeader:@"Cache control" value:@"no-cache"];
            [request44 setProxyHost:host];
            [request44 setProxyPort:port];
            [request44 setFailedBlock:^{
                NSLog(@"failed 2st");
                NSLog(@"%@",request44.error);
            }];
            [request44 setCompletionBlock:^{

                // NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:request44.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

                NSString *urls = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request44.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                // NSLog(@"%@",urls);
                NSArray *urlArray = [urls componentsSeparatedByString:@"http://"];
                NSLog(@"%@",urlArray);

                if (urlArray.count < 2) {
                    return;
                }

                NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",[[[urlArray objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:0]];

                //NSString *url = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",[urlArray lastObject]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
                NSLog(@"%@",url);
                if ([url rangeOfString:@"video"].location != NSNotFound) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",url);
                    ASIHTTPRequest *final = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];


                    [final setProxyHost:host];
                    [final setProxyPort:port];
                    [final addRequestHeader:@"Cache control" value:@"no-cache"];
                    [final addRequestHeader:@"Host" value:@"video11.iad02.hls.twitch.tv"];
                    [final addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"];
                    [final addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"];
                    [final addRequestHeader:@"Accept-Language" value:@"en-US,en;q=0.5"];
                    [final addRequestHeader:@"Accept-Encoding" value:@"gzip, deflate"];
                    [final addRequestHeader:@"Referer" value:@"http://www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.rc356cd0c16b6941b7f81b61f6c81628e0af555d9.swf"];
                    [final addRequestHeader:@"Cookie" value:@"__qca=P0-1674306474-1405279259134; __utma=165406266.651051162.1405279260.1417284372.1417380722.33; __utmz=165406266.1411832471.26.8.utmcsr=twitch.tv|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/nozux; language=en-us; __gads=ID=bc1b6635a26dc0a7:T=1405279267:S=ALNI_MY1rrxM6Qf6aS_lUCRlff0o0gtUaA; unique_id=e8ba8f001f90b6bc293ab6e79ea0b1bb; __utmc=165406266; feature_bucket=88; _twitch_session_id=c06f09efe4c36c8ea46176deabab0cb5; __utmb=165406266.0.10.1417380722; mp_809576468572134f909dffa6bd0dcfcf_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22147312bcdb989-0fc383a2c86945-41652d42-13c680-147312bcdba176%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fintl.gg%2F%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22intl.gg%22%7D"];
                    [final addRequestHeader:@"Connection" value:@"keep-alive"];
                    [final setFailedBlock:^{
                        NSLog(@"final failed");
                    }];
                    [final setCompletionBlock:^{


                        if ([final.responseString rangeOfString:@"#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE"].location != NSNotFound) {
                            [self.builtRequests addObject:final];
                            if (proxyDictonary) {
                                [self.SuccessProxies addObject:proxyDictonary];
                            }

                            [self sendRequest:final];
                            NSLog(@"%lu",_builtRequests.count);
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"%@",final.responseHeaders);
                            NSLog(@"%@",final.responseString);
                        }


                    }];

                    [final startAsynchronous];

                }


            }];
            [request44 startAsynchronous];

        }];
        [request43 startAsynchronous];
```

Here are the response headers from my code when the connections are successful:

```
Request43:"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
Age = 0;
"Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 231;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 03 Dec 2014 20:51:39 GMT";
Etag = "\"151bb8422eb29f9f33a520ab352f152e\"";
"Front-End-Https" = on;
Server = nginx;
Status = "200 OK";
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
Via = "1.1 varnish";
"Www-Authenticate" = "OAuth realm='TwitchTV'";
"X-API-Version" = 3;
"X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"X-MH-Cache" = "appcache2; M";
"X-Request-Id" = 7939f63c1e3130c43a4edfc9a0911629;
"X-Runtime" = "0.030651";
"X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
"X-Varnish" = 1041100800;

Request44:Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 2268;
"Content-Type" = "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl";
Date = "Wed, 03 Dec 2014 20:52:44 GMT";
Server = nginx;
Via = "usher25:8933";
"X-Cache" = "MISS from CLONWLPROX1";
"X-Cache-Lookup" = "MISS from CLONWLPROX1:9999";
final:"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "https://secure.twitch.tv";
Age = 1;
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store, private";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 351;
"Content-Type" = "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 03 Dec 2014 20:57:56 GMT";
Expires = "Wed, 03 Dec 2014 20:57:55 GMT";
"Last-Modified" = "Wed, 03 Dec 2014 20:57:53 GMT";
Server = nginx;
Via = "1.1 CLONWLPROX1 (squid/3.3.8)";
"X-Cache" = "MISS from CLONWLPROX1";
"X-Cache-Lookup" = "MISS from CLONWLPROX1:9999";
```

Here are the response headers from firefox when i go to a stream through the browser.

```
request44:Accept-Ranges:bytes
```

Age:0
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:230
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 03 Dec 2014 21:07:44 GMT
ETag:"74252dca9d2cf4e5da6f91f0d9fcc6c0"
Front-End-Https:on
Server:nginx
Status:200 OK
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 varnish
WWW-Authenticate:OAuth realm='TwitchTV'
X-API-Version:3
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-MH-Cache:appcache2; M
X-Request-Id:13c6dbe385ebb778b21596eadb83f4bc
X-Runtime:0.060941
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Varnish:1048532873

```
request44:Connection:keep-alive
```

Content-Length:2252
Content-Type:application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
Date:Wed, 03 Dec 2014 21:07:44 GMT
Server:nginx
via:usher16:8947

```
final:Accept-Ranges:bytes
```

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://secure.twitch.tv
Age:0
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:351
Content-Type:application/vnd.apple.mpegurl; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 03 Dec 2014 21:07:46 GMT
Expires:Wed, 03 Dec 2014 21:07:47 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=50
Last-Modified:Wed, 03 Dec 2014 21:07:42 GMT
Server:nginx

Comment: its a wall of text sorry about that ppl who try to read it but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are running into Twitch's anti viewbot code.  No one has been able to crack how it works yet.  They have not talked about it at all.  It seems to be temperamental.  Sometimes it works really well and other times it seems to do a half job.  Some people think they randomize the results when the detect a bot in order to confuse bot writers.  Clearly Twitch has too much time.

Comment: Wow that is impressive but there must be a way to trick.  And viewbotting still exists if we look at the twitter bot detector.

Comment: The twitter bots detect the difference between people in chat and viewcount. They do not understand channels on front page. Or channels that are embeded in another site.

Comment: well damn.  they really did a good job at stoping the viewbots.  At least i had a few times booting my friend to 4k ppl probably should tell him now lol.